# Python Django Forms Email Validation clean_email doesn't work

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, email

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import SignUpForm
from .models import SignUp

class SignUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__unicode__", 'timestamp', 'updated']
    form = SignUpForm

admin.site.register(SignUp)
```

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class SignUp(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUp

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['full_name', 'email']

    def clean_email(self):  # It seems that this clean_email method doesn't work
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_base, provider = email.split('@')
        domain, extension = provider.split('.')
        if not extension == 'edu':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please use a valid .EDU email address")
        return email
```

If we add user in Admin Panel and email hasn't "edu" extension, the ValidationError should raise. But this doesn't happen. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told the admin to use your custom ModelAdmin class.

Do this:

```
admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
```